# Add additional input fields based on user input

Tags: objective-c, field

I would like to allow my user to be able to say that he wants to pay out n positions in his tournament. Then be able to go in and have n fields listed and the ability to put different amounts in each one in order. I know how to do this in web code but have no idea how to do it in objective-c. Is it possible to add fields dynamically? If so, how do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look at the API documentation for NSMatrix, which handles groups of cells. You could use it to create a column (or row, or several of each) of text fields, and the number of cells is easily changeable. The problem you'll have is resizing your window and moving anything below your matrix of text fields so nothing collides.

You can create an NSMatrix in Interface Builder with "Layout -> Embed Objects In -> Matrix" (selecting your text field first).